# Taking usernames with numbers without using break in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
username='smith123'
numbers='1234567890'
for i in username:
    if i in numbers:
        print(username)
        #break
```

Hello, I  write a code that if a number exist in username, then it is printed, but in such usernames, the usernames are printed 3 times. To make sure that it will be printed just one time, is there any method without using break? Thanks.

Comment: maybe try not using a `for` loop

Comment: There could be completely different ways to do that, but `break`ing out of the loop as soon as your condition is satisfied is the right thing to do...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
username='smith123'

if any(char.isdigit() for char in username):
    print(username)
```

docs:
[any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any),
[isdigit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit),
[(list) comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)

Answer (score 0):

Just another way using [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> \w
>
> For Unicode (str) patterns:
>
> Matches Unicode word characters; this includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the underscore. If the ASCII flag is used, only [a-zA-Z0-9_] is matched.

```
import re
username="smith123"
if re.match(r"^\w+$", username):
    print(username)
```

Comment: `^` is unnecessary because  `re.match` is anchored at the beginning of the string

Comment: while re might be a good solution in general this particular solution does not fit the question asked about finding out "if the username contains numbers". This solution prints the username if it only consists of "word characters" instead.

Comment: @Raphael it was example regexp to fit example string from question and I think you could simply leave edit suggestion without these useless comments 